# Syntax of Adding user Menu in moodle

Tags: menu, themes, moodle

I am trying to add user menus in moodle 3.3.1 version but i am facing some problem in understanding the meaning of each terms "langstringname, componentname". can you please explain them with any example.

Answer (score 0):

Language strings in Moodle are stored within a particular plugin and given an identifier within that plugin.

So, for example, the HTML block has English language strings stored in "blocks/html/lang/en/block_html.php". This file includes lines such as:

```
$string['leaveblanktohide'] = 'leave blank to hide the title';
```

To output 'leave blank to hide the title' (or the translated equivalent in the user's own language) from your code, you would write:

```
echo get_string('leaveblanktohide', 'block_html');
```

Where 'leaveblanktohide' is the 'langstringname' referred to in your question and 'block_html' is the 'componentname' referred to in your question.

Comment: Thanks @davosmith it helped me, but still i have little bit confusion, how do i know these value. for example i want to add a user menu item for "Private files" than what will be the values("'langstringname" , "componentname") for it ? how i can know ? where to check ? i hope you understand my problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can choose whatever you want for 'langstringname'. If you are creating a plugin to hold your code changes, then the 'componentname' should match the name of your plugin (e.g. if the plugin was called 'myplugin' and it was a local plugin 'local_myplugin', if it was a block 'block_myplugin'). If you are hacking core code (bad idea), then you could put it in lang/en/moodle.php and set the 'componentname' to 'moodle' (or leave it blank).